# discrete- mathematical proof to support the statement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

lets assume i have three children , tim,jack and juliet. currently tim is 14 years old , jack is 10 years and juliet is 6 years old.
next year => tim:15, jack=11, juliet=7 and so on....

Is it possible that all of the three children will have an age that are a prime number, in the same year?

i know by checking the prime numbers list that it is not possible , but is there a mathematical proof(expression,equation,formula ) to have as an argument ? if there is not mathematical proof of that, what would your argument be? how would you convince me that it is not possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $6+n$, $10+n$ and $14+n$ are all primes, then $n$ must be odd. So we can let $n=2k+1$.

Hence we need to prove $2k+7$, $2k+11$ and $2k+15$ can not be primes simultaneously.

1. If we let $k=3p$, then $2k+15=6p+15=3(2p+5)$ is not prime.
2. If we let $k=3p+1$, then $2k+7=6p+9=3(2p+3)$ is not prime.
3. If we let $k=3p+2$, then $2k+11=6p+15=3(2p+5)$ is not prime.

Thus, the three number cannot be all primes.

Comment: what do you mean by k=3p?

Comment: @humble24 $p$ is another non-negative integer. All the integers can be seen as multiplies of 3, multiplies of 3 plus 1, or multiplies of 3 plus 2. Here I want to show no matter in what case, there's one can not be a prime.

Comment: Alright  but" All the integers can be seen as multiplies of 3, multiplies of 3 plus 1, or multiplies of 3 plus 2" i am not sure i understand you what mean here?.  and isnt it enough evidence to only have case nr 1?

Comment: I just mean if you divide $k$ by 3 the reminder will be 0, 1, or 2. If you only have case 1 (the reminder is 0), you may not sure what will happen if the reminder of $k$ is 1 or 2. So we have to discuss all the three cases.

Comment: Thanks for explaining , but i am still missing something . Could explain really simply why you choose to  let k be 3p ? why not 1p ? how do you choose your k-value?

Comment: @humble24 I think you mean "why I think about 3". While you replace $n$ as $2k+1$, looking at $2k+7$, $2k+11$ and $2k+15$, you will find this idea because $7=2 \times 3 +1$, $11= 3 \times 3 +2$ and $15= 5 \times 3$. It means no matter what will be the reminder of $k$ divided by $3$, one of them must be multiply of 3, as here I've shown. I won't choose $k=p$ of course, because it won't make any sense. Another reason for using $3$ is that there are only 3 numbers. If you choice primes larger than $3$, you will find there will be cases undefined whether the numbers are prime or not.

Comment: If we let k=3p+1, then 2k+11=6p+12. shouldnt we get 6p +13 ?

Comment: @humble24 So sorry I get this wrong... fixed.

Comment: nope no problem, i believe i fully understand it now. In case i get new questions i will be back :D. Thanks alot !

Comment: btw how do you see that the three number cannot be all primes? what are you refering to ?

Comment: @humble24 I won't see it if you didn't say it is impossible. However, one can always try this kind of way to find whether they can be all primes or not. You can try to find $n$ such that $n+2$, $n+6$, $n+8$ and $n+14$ are all primes to find if you really understand this method.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.

$14+2k,10+2k,6+2k\gt 2$ are even. So, we want three numbers $14+2k-1,10+2k-1,6+2k-1$ to be primes.

- For $k\equiv 0\pmod 3$, $10+2k-1\equiv 9\equiv 0\pmod 3$.
- For $k\equiv 1\pmod 3$, $14+2k-1\equiv 15\equiv 0\pmod 3$.
- For $k\equiv 2\pmod 3$, $6+2k-1\equiv 9\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

So, one of the three numbers is a multiple of $3$ and is larger than $3$, so is not a prime.

Comment: Thanks for you answer as well , i prefered Asydot answer that why i marked his answer :) .

Comment: What do you mean  by one of the three numbers is a multiple of 3 that is larger than 3?

Comment: one of the three numbers is a multiple of 3 and it is larger than 3, but are they not all  multiple of 3 and and larger than 3? 15 and 9 are larger than 3 or do you mean something else ?

Comment: @humble24: Let us call the three numbers $a,b,c$. I meant that one of $a,b,c$ is always of the form $3k$ where $k\ge 2$. Let $a=3k$ where $k\ge 2$. Then, $a$ is not a prime. In short, there is at least one number of the three that is not a prime.

Comment: alright, thanks mate :)